# Best Practice for JAR Dependency Deployment

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have an application that is being deployed to an AIX machine as an executable JAR. I used Maven shade to build an Uber JAR that has all of my dependencies packed in the JAR; Spring, Logback, and javax.mail. The application is called by another program executing a shell script. That all works fine. The DBA has asked that I remove of all of the dependencies from the JAR, place them in directories on the AIX machine, and include those locations in the CLASSPATH of the AIX user. He indicated that this was best practice. I have used the `<scope>provided</scope>`  tag before in Maven to not package dependencies that the Container would provide, but I have never run into this type of request with a JAR. Is this a best practice with this sort of scenario?

Comment: Re-use? Thats the only solid answer I have gotten thus far.

Comment: Why would there be a separated lib folder which contains all jars instead of having them packaged into a single jar which simply can be started by `java -jar ...`? Making a classpath user agnostic sounds strange? This can be achieved by the appassemlber maven plugin...which can generate the shell scripts to handle the classpath generation etc....

Comment: If you start to re-use parts of the libs you have introduce a share library which makes updating more complicated if not impossible...better go the path self-contained....

Comment: I finally got an answer to this. It is to prevent redundant dependencies being packaged with distinct JARs on the same server and also to allow new versions of dependencies to be deployed to the directories defined in the user's Linux CLASSPATH; so if logback has a minor rev for example, removing the old JAR and adding the new one wouldn't require recompilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Uber-JAR the dependencies are not visible. But there are a lot of people out there, which need to know and list all dependencies, because they need to publish a list of all license (for example gnu,asf...) used in the application.

So if you need a clear listing of all dependencies, then the Uber-JAR is not the best practice you should go.